# Executor Service does not timeout and continues to run

Tags: java, twitter4j, executorservice

I have the following code:

```
  def getIndustryData(String[] theIndustries) {

            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt")))

            //Listens to Twitter statuses and carries out the following methods on the status
            StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
                @Override
                void onStatus(Status status) {

                    printWriter.write(status.getLang() + "|||" + status.getText())
                    printWriter.println()
                }

                @Override
                void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {

                }

                @Override
                void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {

                }

                @Override
                void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {

                }

                @Override
                void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {

                }

                @Override
                void onException(Exception ex) {

                }
            }

            TwitterStream stream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance()
            stream.addListener(listener)
            FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery()
            fq.track(theIndustries)
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

            Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                String call() throws Exception {

                    stream.filter(fq)
                    return null
                }
            })

            try {

                future.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

            } catch (TimeoutException e) {

                stream.removeListener(listener)
                stream.shutdown()
                future.cancel(true)
                executor.shutdownNow()

            }
        }
```

I am using Twitter4J to access the Twitter API.I want to write tweets to a file for 2 minutes and then stop.

The `stream.filter(fq)` method runs even after the stated 2 minutes and the TimeoutException is never reached. I thought after the 2 minutes the exception would be caught and I could end the method however this does not happen.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. This code won't even compile.

Comment: @AndyTurner, You will need Twitter API keys in order to run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong mental model of how TwitterStream works and also most probably of how standard java `Future` and `ExecutorService` work.

TwitterStream  doesn't work on any Thread you provide to it. `TwitterStream .filter` starts new thread internally as you can see at the source at https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-stream/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterStreamImpl.java#L317 and https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-stream/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterStreamImpl.java#L516

Also `Future.get` with timeout method is not guaranteed to fail with `TimeoutException`. If the job is fast, it just returns value. And this is exactly your case! `stream.filter(fq)` creates new `Thread` which is fast and then your future immediately returns `null`.

The simplest (but probably not the best) way to make it work is something like this

```java
stream.filter(fq)
try
{
    Thread.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000); // just sleep on the caller thread
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    // ignore
}
stream.removeListener(listener)
stream.cleanup()
//stream.shutdown()     //don't think you really need shutdown, cleanup seems to be enough
```